# do any scripting languages support midi?

Tags: scripting, midi

like the question says... are there any scripting languages i can learn that let you use midi?

Comment: Why couldn't you just do a Google search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has the PMIDI library which will probably suit what your needs.
http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

Answer (score 2):

Perl has modules that deals with midi as well. [Search CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=midi&mode=all) for more

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like C (plenty of MIDI libraries out there for it) and use a binding to something like Lua or Angelscript.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby also have a [MIDI library](https://rubygems.org/gems/midilib).